# Can we connect MongoDB from logic Apps without using cosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio, azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to connect MongoDB from my logic App without using CosmosDB. is it possible by any other way?

Comment: Sure. Take a look [MongoDB Drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/)

Comment: >Server version 3.6 of the MongoDB

Comment: You have multiple options but would involve either bit of a coding or configuration.
1. Create your custom connector in logic apps and interact with your mongo instance Ref- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank
2. Create azure function which can interact with your mongo instance and call it from within your existing logic app Ref - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb
3. Create azure data factory flow / pipeline which can talk to you mongo instance and invoke the data factory pipeline from within your logic app

Comment: @Bhushan thanks for you solution but can it be possible without Azure function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no [`connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/) available with Logic Apps to connect to MongoDB directly.

As mentioned in the comment, you need to use the Azure Function with Cosmosdb API or with data factory as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think all that's needed is for you to [set up a webhook endpoint](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/services/http/) on your MongoDB collection, and send a formed request to it.